# How to add two def function in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def get_total_co2_electric(self, obj):
        totalpieces = ElectricBike.objects.all().aggregate(total_co2_electric=Sum('co2'))
        return totalpieces["total_co2_electric"]

# Total Co2 save by Electric
def get_total_co2_classic(self, obj):
    totalprice = ClassicBike.objects.all().aggregate(total_co2_classic=Sum('co2'))
    return totalprice["total_co2_classic"]

def get_total_co2(self):
    totalprice = (self.get_total_co2_classic() + self.get_total_co2_electric())
    return totalprice
```

I am trying to add this two def tag and get result but i am getting error "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
So how to add this

Comment: Remove the `obj` parameter.

Comment: i did brother but still i getting same error

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error message? It's not clear from your question what had 2 arguments given.

Comment: @RobStreeting "get_total_co2_electric() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" This is error message and i remove obj from all

Comment: Are you adding these functions to a class ?

Comment: show us the context in which these functions are defined. Also it's not possible you get this error with just the code you're showing. Please edit your question so that it's reproducible for someone trying to help you. It should be a [mcve].

Comment: You don't need ```self``` if it's just functions not methods of class

Answer (score 0):

You remove the obj and do some thing like this

```
def get_total_co2_electric(self):
    totalpieces = ElectricBike.objects.all().aggregate(total_co2_electric=Sum('co2'))
    return totalpieces["total_co2_electric"]
```

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: `from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard',views.Dashboard.as_view())
]`    Here is the urls.py

Comment: views.Dashboard.as_view() is for class based views but you are using Def, you remove as_view() and it becomes from . import views urlpatterns = [ path('dashboard',views.Dashboard, name='Dashboard') ]